# MemoryError in IPython (using Windows)

Tags: python, memory, numpy

I've been trying to initialize an numpy array of integers in IPython that is 1000 x 1000 x 120, and every time I get a `MemoryError`. I don't know why this would be the case since it's really not that big of an array.

My code is simply:

```
bigLattice = np.zeros((numsimulations,end2+1,t+1))
```

Let me know if there's something I can fix so that numpy can access more memory.

Answer (score 3):

The default type for floating point numbers is float64, so the size of your matrix is 915Mb

```
In [1]: a = np.zeros((1000,1000,120))

In [2]: %whos
Variable   Type       Data/Info
-------------------------------
a          ndarray    1000x1000x120: 120000000 elems, type `float64`, 960000000 bytes (915 Mb)
```

[Here's a link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) to where you can find details about available `dtypes` and their limits.

If you only need to store integer values of one byte then you can instantiate with `int8` values:

```
np.zeros((1000,1000,120),dtype=np.int8)
```

which would reduce the size to 114Mb:

```
%whos
Variable   Type       Data/Info
-------------------------------
a          ndarray    1000x1000x120: 120000000 elems, type `int8`, 120000000 bytes (114 Mb
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Is there a way to use integer values that are more than 255?

Comment: `uint16` or `uint32`, depends on your needs. 228Mb for uint16 and 457Mb for uint32